# Android MapView trying to add view, but already has parent

Tags: android, view, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.maplayout);
// Create Rotate view
mRotateView = new RotateView(this);

// create a map view
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

mRotateView.addView(mapView); // error here
setContentView(mRotateView);
mylocation = new MyLocationOverlay(this,mapView);
```

But when I add the view I get an error that says that the specified child already has a parent. I assume this is because the mapView is already a child of the layout.

So, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option #1: Put `RotateView` in your `res/layout/maplayout.xml` resource as the parent of the `MapView` widget, so you do not have to set that up in Java code.

Option #2: Remove the `MapView` from your `res/layout/maplayout.xml` resource, create an instance of it via its constructor, and add it to your `RotateView` in Java code.

Option #3: Call `removeView()` on the parent to remove the `MapView` from it before calling `addView()` to add it to the `RotateView`.